# Magento images are not showing up frontend

Tags: magento, migration

I have migrated Magento to other server most of images are showing up but images of some products with particular category not showing up.What i have tried:-

1.Disabled cache
2.Refreshed Indexes
3.Deleted all stuff from media/catalogue/products/cache

But still images not showing up.

Comment: Make sure that you set the right permission on all magento files: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

Also make sure that the new server meets all system requirements http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements

Comment: Also (obviously) make sure the images exist in the correct folder path.

Comment: image exist in correct folder path

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few weeks ago, and it was not a problem of code but of usage, i was uploading images bigger than 4000x4000 pixels, if you upload smaller images (1000x100 could do the job for high definition front end zoom and performance) it works.

Hope it works for you.